# Why is this questions deleted/downvoted

Tags: discussion

I asked whether prostitutes are happy with their job

Basically I am motivated by this quote:

> Whatever the legal definition, an implication made by people who don't
>   like prostitution is that the prostitutes are forcibly dragged into
>   the trade and would not have been if it was illegal. Both of which as
>   pure BS - as noted, even the biggest bust involved people voluntarily
>   coming to US, and a vast majority of such cases nationwide are not
>   involved in sex trade, legal or illegal

[Does legalizing prostitution lead to an increase in human trafficking?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3579/does-legalizing-prostitution-lead-to-an-increase-in-human-trafficking?rq=1)

So I asked a question

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10873/are-prostitutes-happy-with-their-job

I gave 3 sources. All are reliable.

I am curious about people claiming that governments' rather than individuals should run people's life. That defy all economic courses I learn in school. Econ 101 says humans are selfish and yet this "other" claim that they know how to run our life. Aren't you skeptical? Am I the only one being skeptical?

Comment: Meta is not the place to continue the argument of your post on the main site. Your choice of terminology is also highly offensive, we expect users to be civil here, terms denigrating specific persons or groups are not welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Simple. You continually ask question with a misogynist tone or agenda. You continually ask questions about vague concepts which are hardly leading to constructive answers.

So your question is irritating and poorly answerable with objectivity, ergo *Subjective and Argumentative*, which are clear-cut, no-questions-asked close reasons.

It was deleted because it was unsalvageable and was being tanked with down votes, and was flagged.

Also, because you have dozens of bad questions like this and are showing very little signs of improving the questions once they are posted.

Please  **absolutely abstain** from asking this kind of questions here from now on.

Comment: I didn't know asking whether someone is happy means hating them. Anyway. Does asking question with mysogynist agenda makes the question inappropriate for this stack? Is asking whether someone is happy too vague to answer?

Comment: Is the issue because the term happy is vague or because it differs from feminists claim? I want to know if politically incorrect question is within the scope or not.

Comment: @JimThio The fact that you are oblivious to how offensive the term 'Feminazi' is is quite revealing.

Comment: @JimThio: What's unclear in what I said? Coming here with an agenda will get you banned. Asking vague and unanswerable questions will also get you banned. Neither of these statements is up for discussion. Feel free to complain with StackExchange if you disagree.

Comment: How come the question is vague? Also how come perceived agenda makes a question off topic? Finally if someone want to run your life under the pretext of your own good, what do you call such people? Fascist? Nazi?

Comment: Nazi n. 2.b. hyperbolically. A person who is perceived to be authoritarian, autocratic, or inflexible; one who seeks to impose his or her views upon others.  --- If someone told us that he or she is the one that has the right to decide what we do with our own life, and then demand that government run our life and claim it's for our own good, what do we call that person? By the way pro market libertarian is closer to what I am than misogynist. My actual intent for the question is actually curiosity. I thought sceptic stack exchange works under assumption that you can never know intent.

Answer (score 2):

your sources are essentially three anecdotal cases that could represent 1% of prostitutes and the other 99% could be the opposite, or not we have now way of knowing.

Comment: So that's your claim. No body sceptical about it? DVK doesn't seem to agree.

Comment: So your claim is that only 1% of prostitutes are happy to do their job and most of them would rather work at McDonald, or battlefield?

Comment: Even if it's true that only 1% of prostitution is happy, why not cite source and answer it rather than squelching questions?

Comment: What do you mean we have no way of knowing?

Comment: @JimThio the only way to actually get an answer is to find a statistically significant survey of an unknown population, that has major confounding factors involved. If the question could be asked in a way that the scope was limited enough to be answerable I would be in favor of it being allowed. "Are prostitutes happy that work in a regulated and licensed environment happy?" would be an answerable question.